# Autodesk login page is failing to load from Desktop app

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

We have a Desktop app that is integrated to authenticate the user login through Autodesk. Unfortunately, the link to `https://accounts.autodesk.com/logon?resume=%2Fas%2FFp2fv%2Fresume%2Fas%2Fauthorization.ping&spentity=null#username` is loading only the footer of the page. While debugging we noticed that there are few javascript errors on the Autodesk sign-in page that is causing the issue.
Here is the screenshot of the error message.

[Login Page Load Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixSSr.png)

[image]

However, this does not seem to be a problem when we are using the login through Austodesk from our website.
Could someone look into this issue and suggest a possible fix. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the .NET desktop sample that is doing log-in inside a CefSharp component? That has been working fine: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-viewhubs-desktop